# Use three transformations (average, max, min) of pretrained embeddings to a single output layer in Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, word-embedding

I have developed a trivial Feed Forward neural network with Pytorch.

The neural network uses GloVe pre-trained embeddings in a freezed `nn.Embeddings` layer.

Next, the embedding layer splits into three embeddings. Each split is a different transformation applied to the initial embedding layer. Then the embeddings layer feed three `nn.Linear` layers. And finally I have a single output layer for a binary classification target.

The shape of the embedding tensor is [64,150,50]
-> 64: sentences in the batch,
-> 150: words per sentence,
-> 50: vector-size of a single word (pre-trained GloVe vector)

So after the transformation, the embedding layer splits into three layers with shape [64,50], where 50 = either the `torch.mean()`,  `torch.max()` or `torch.min()` of the 150 words per sentence.

My questions are:

1. How could I feed the output layer from three different `nn.Linear` layers to predict a single target value [0,1].
2. Is this efficient and helpful to the total predictive power of the model? Or just selecting the average of the embeddings is sufficient and no improvement will be observed.

The `forward()` method of my PyTorch model is:

```py
  def forward(self, text):

    embedded = self.embedding(text)
    if self.use_pretrained_embeddings:
      embedded_average = torch.mean(embedded, dim=1)
      embedded_max = torch.max(embedded, dim=1)[0]
      embedded_min = torch.min(embedded, dim=1)[0]
    else:
      embedded = self.flatten_layer(embedded)

    input_layer = self.input_layer(embedded_average) #each Linear layer has the same value of hidden unit
    input_layer = self.activation(input_layer)

    input_layer_max = self.input_layer(embedded_max)
    input_layer_max = self.activation(input_layer_max)

    input_layer_min = self.input_layer(embedded_min)
    input_layer_min = self.activation(input_layer_min)
    
    #What should I do here? to exploit the weights of the 3 hidden layers
    output_layer = self.output_layer(input_layer)
    output_layer = self.activation_output(output_layer) #Sigmoid()
    
    return output_layer
```

After the proposed answer the function is:

```py
  def forward(self, text):

    embedded = self.embedding(text)
    if self.use_pretrained_embeddings:
      embedded_average = torch.mean(embedded, dim=1)
      embedded_max = torch.max(embedded, dim=1)[0]
      embedded_min = torch.min(embedded, dim=1)[0]

      #use of average embeddings transformation
      input_layer_average = self.input_layer(embedded_average)
      input_layer_average = self.activation(input_layer_average)
      
      #use of max embeddings transformation
      input_layer_max = self.input_layer(embedded_max)
      input_layer_max = self.activation(input_layer_max)

      #use of min embeddings transformation
      input_layer_min = self.input_layer(embedded_min)
      input_layer_min = self.activation(input_layer_min)

    else:
      embedded = self.flatten_layer(embedded)

    input_layer = torch.concat([input_layer_average, input_layer_max, input_layer_min], dim=1)
    input_layer = self.activation(input_layer)

    print("3",input_layer.shape) #[192,1] vs [64,1] -> output layer

    if self.n_layers !=0:
      for layer in self.layers:
          input_layer = layer(input_layer)

    output_layer = self.output_layer(input_layer)
    output_layer = self.activation_output(output_layer)
    
    return output_layer
```

This generates the following error:

> ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([192, 1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.

Expected outcome since the concatenated layer is 3x the size of the sentences (64). Any fix that could resolve it?

Comment: Replying by your username "Cheers mate" :)

Comment: You may want to ask Q2 in more relevant sites e.g., Cross Validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding 1: You can use [torch.concat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.concat.html) to concatenate the outputs along the appropriate dimension, and then e.g. map them to a single output using another linear layer.

Regarding 2: You will have to try it yourself and see whether this is useful.

Comment: Having applied the ```torch.concat()``` I have a ```ValueError``` about the dimension of the outputl layer. 
```ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([192, 1])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.```

This is because output_layer (64 batches, 1 target) whereas the concat layer is 3x64 = 192 since I have three input layers (of three transformations). How could I bypass this?

Comment: @NikSp Just change the size of the output layer wherever it is created?

Comment: Yes, It's completed. Multiplication of linear_hidden_units by 3 for the output layer and the problem solved :) Kudos for the help and the ideas!! I have accepted your answer :)